# Automate moving mouse to series of co-ordinates and click

Tags: qgis, python

I have 4 .tif files that I have loaded in QGIS and I am looking to extract data at very specific locations using mutant. I have the points I want loaded in as a csv file and there is a large number of them. Whilst I could manually go to each point and use mutant to locate the data I'm looking for the process can be quite tedious and can be open to errors. Is there a way to automate this process?

Steps I want to automate:

```
1. Send cursor to specific location
2. Use a click event or manipulate mutant to retrieve data at that point
3. Export that data to a csv or dataframe like structure
4. Iterate over to next location
```

I have read up on this link which only seems to provide me half the answer and not how to send a click event or manipulate mutant. [Is there a way to take control of the mouse pointer using python in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/108850/is-there-a-way-to-take-control-of-the-mouse-pointer-using-python-in-qgis)

I am familiar with python and that is what I intend to use to automate this process

Comment: Are you just wanting the pixel RGB values at the x/y locations?  Also, do the tif images overlap?

Comment: Yes the tif images overlap and if by RGB values you mean the value of the tif image at those specific co-ordinates then that is what I'm looking for.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129847/obtain-coordinates-and-corresponding-pixel-values-from-geotiff-using-python-gdal

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely automate this using python (pyqgis).  Here is one approach:

1. Load all the tifs into QGIS
2. Using python loop through the csv and set variables for the x, y values
3. Use this q/a answer from gene to get the raster x/y pixel value, [Retrieve pixel value from raster layer in pyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/189269/retrieve-pixel-value-from-raster-layer-in-pyqgis)

I'm not sure if the tifs have the same pixel values at their overlap, but you may want to take that into consideration when pulling values out if a location is at an overlap.